# How to generate and insert large dataset in db2?

Tags: database, jdbc, db2

I changed code and this code insert 30 000 row/min , but it is too slow. My be anybody give me another idea how to improved speed?

```
Connection connection = poolledConnection.getConnection(); 
connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
int bathcount = 0; 
Statement st = connection.createStatement(); 
    for (condit){ 
        st.addBatch(sql); 
            if (bathcount >= 10000){ 
                st.executeBatch(); 
                connection.commit(); 
                st.clearBatch();
                bathcount = 0; 
            }
        bathcount++; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: On which type of platform are you using DB2?  DB2 z/OS, DB2 LUW, or DB2 for i?

Comment: I use DB2 LUW (Windows).

Comment: Consider using batch updates: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvbtupd.html

Comment: Have you profiled the code? Where is the slowness coming from?

Comment: Please see message before.

Comment: Are you looking for something like that?

[What is the fastest way to insert 1 mln+ records in DB2 table?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21302912/1537313

Comment: The comment from @mustaccio is probably relevant. Especially review the section in that link starting with "To make batch updates using a single statement with several sets of input parameters..." nearly a third of the way down the page. Note that `addBatch()` is executed many times before `executeBatch()` applies the group that was added so far essentially as a single statement. It's not clear from the docs if a `blocked INSERT` is effected. See [Blocked inserts with JDBC](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaha%2Fbatchblo.htm) for somewhat related example.

Comment: This might be a better secondary example [Fast inserts with JDBC batch](http://www.channeldb2.com/profiles/blogs/fast-inserts-with-jdbc-batch) for faster batch INSERTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Statement, instead of PreparedStatement, it is likely that DB2 is doing a prepare for each of your insert statements. Doing the prepare once, instead of thousands, or millions of times will save you a significant amount of CPU time.

In order to improve the speed, you should have a SQL statement with parameter markers, and set those parameters for each row.

I'm assuming that in your example, you must be building the SQL somehow for each row. If I'm wrong, and you're using the same insert values for each row, you can skip setting the parameter values, and it will be even faster.

So for my suggested change, it would look something like this (I'm assuming this is Java):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TBL (COLS...) VALUES (?,?...)";

Connection connection = poolledConnection.getConnection(); 
connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
int bathcount = 0; 
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
    for (MyObject object : objectList /*conduit???*/){
        ps.setString(1,object.getVal1());
        ps.setString(2,object.getVal2()); 
        ps.addBatch(); 
            if (bathcount >= 10000){ 
                ps.executeBatch(); 
                connection.commit(); 
                bathcount = 0; 
            }
        bathcount++; 
    } 
    /* Make sure you add this to get the last batch if it's not exactly 10k*/
    if (batchcount > 0) {
       ps.executeBatch(); 
       connection.commit(); 
    }
}
```