# What is the fastest way to insert 1 mln+ records in DB2 table?

Tags: sql, insert, db2

In C# I have 1mln+ records which are necessary to insert into DB2 table.
What is the fastest way to insert 1 mln+ records in DB2 table?

I've check several way and the fastest is by 1000 rows basing on the following request: 
INSERT INTO tbl (id, rel) values (1, 2), (2,3),...

Are the any other ideas?

Comment: Is there a question here? What platform are you trying to do this on? Are you wanting to do this through a programming language, or just DB2 tools?

Comment: If you really want fastest, use LOAD utility. It takes slightly more work if you are working remotely, but is still doable.

Comment: insert from C# and DB2 8.2 where LOAD is not accessible via client

Answer (score 0):

Try wth something like that for 1000 records:

```
INSERT INTO table
  SELECT                                       
  cast (RAND()*50000 as numeric(6)) AS id,  
  cast (RAND() as varchar(30)) AS rel,       
  FROM qsys2/COLUMNS                           
   fetch first 1000 rows only
```

change `table` and the field nature/length in relation with you table.

I assumed with that

```
cast (RAND()*50000 as numeric(6)) AS id
```

that `id` is numeric 6 byte

with the last line you limit 1000 rows insert